# How can I link Rcpp if there is no libRcpp.so file?

Tags: c++, r, linux, rcpp, rinside

When trying to compile my C++ program, I am linking my R files but Rcpp doesn't have a libRcpp.so file.

Here is the R code (I've left out the c++):

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>   
#include <RInside.h>

**** some c++ code*****

RInside R(argc, argv);

    string cmd = "tmpf <- tempfile('nums');"
                 "png(tmpf);"
                 "counts <- table(a,b,c,d,e);"
                 "barplot(counts, main='My Plot', xlab='Letters');"
                 "dev.off();"
                 "tmpf";

    string tmpfile = R.parseEval(cmd);

    cout << "Using plot " << tmpfile << endl;
    unlink(tmpfile.c_str());
```

Then I compile with g++ like:

```
g++ -I/home/robert/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include  
-I/home/robert/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RInside/include 
-I/usr/share/R/include -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR 
-L/home/robert/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/libs -lRcpp 
-L/home/robert/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RInside/lib -lRInside 
Frequency-Analyzer.cpp
```

The error reads:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRcpp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is because 
    `-L/home/robert/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/libs` 
does not lead to a 
`"libRcpp.so"` 
file. BUT, there is no lib file within my directory because it no longer supports linking. How can I possible compile with RInside then??

Comment: Use the (GNU)Makefile(s) included with RInside in the examples/ directory.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. This helped me understand how programs are built a little better also

Comment: Glad to know.  Feel free to accept the answer below then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using something similar to, say, [rinside_sample15.cpp](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside/blob/master/inst/examples/standard/rinside_sample15.cpp). I can easily build that *by using the supplied and tested `Makefile`*:

```
edd@don:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$ make -f GNUmakefile 
    rinside_sample15
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include \
   -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/include \
   -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security \
   -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused \
   -pedantic -Wall    rinside_sample15.cpp  -Wl,--export-dynamic \
   -fopenmp  -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl \
   -lm  -lblas -llapack  -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib \
   -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RInside/lib \
   -o rinside_sample15
edd@don:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$
edd@don:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$ ./rinside_sample15 
Can now use plot in /tmp/xyplot56466f672e73.png
edd@don:~/git/rinside/inst/examples/standard(master)$
```

The path will differ for you, and you may not have `ccache` but it should still work -- or you have issues with your R installation.

Comment: When I try your suggestion, I get this error:
   " /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llzma"    
    "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"    
    "make: *** [rinside_sample8] Error 1"

Comment: Install the dev package for that library.